# How can Index be implemented on an enum with variants of different types?

Tags: rust, enums, slice, traits

I'm trying to implement `Index` on my enum so that I can take slices of it (an enum of the same variant with a sliced inner value), following [Implementing slice for custom type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57203009/2854284). But because my enum has variants with different types I can't get it to work:

```rust
pub enum GlkArray<'a> {
    U8(&'a mut [u8]),
    U32(&'a mut [u32]),
}

impl<'a, Idx> Index<Idx> for GlkArray<'a>
where Idx: SliceIndex<[usize]>
{
    type Output = GlkArray<'a>;
    fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output {
        match self {
            GlkArray::U8(buf) => &GlkArray::U8(&mut buf[index]),
            GlkArray::U32(buf) => &GlkArray::U32(&mut buf[index]),
        }
    }
}
```

This results in these errors:

```
error[E0277]: the type `[u8]` cannot be indexed by `Idx`
   --> remglk/src/glkapi/arrays.rs:117:53
    |
117 |             GlkArray::U8(buf) => &GlkArray::U8(&buf[index]),
    |                                                     ^^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
    |
    = note: required for `[u8]` to implement `Index<Idx>`
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
112 | where Idx: SliceIndex<[usize]> + std::slice::SliceIndex<[u8]>
    |                                ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

error[E0277]: the type `[u32]` cannot be indexed by `Idx`
   --> remglk/src/glkapi/arrays.rs:118:55
    |
118 |             GlkArray::U32(buf) => &GlkArray::U32(&buf[index]),
    |                                                       ^^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
    |
    = note: required for `[u32]` to implement `Index<Idx>`
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
112 | where Idx: SliceIndex<[usize]> + std::slice::SliceIndex<[u32]>
    |                                +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I kind of understand that `SliceIndex` wants to be defined over a concrete type, but I'm not sure what to do in this situation. Yes you don't know what variant the enum has from outside, but it's returning another encapsulated enum, so I'm hoping that's okay.

Any ideas how `Idx` needs to be defined, or any alternative suggestions of what I could do instead?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't implement `Index` or `IndexMut` for this type. `Index` is definitely impossible and `IndexMut` seems to not work for lifetime reasons.

Comment: @drewtato Ahh, that's unfortunate. I guess I can create my own slice function rather than using the trait.

Comment: Yeah it's a very frustrating limitation of the `Index` and `IndexMut` traits: they have to return *a reference* so any sort of non-trivial item is impossible (e.g. can't implement it on a bitset and return a bool or new bitset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't implement `Index` for this type since it would require producing new `&mut` references from behind a `&` reference, which is impossible.

Even when `Index` can't be implemented correctly, it's still possible that `IndexMut` could be implemented by making a panicking `Index` implementation, but `IndexMut` is also impossible because of lifetime and ownership issues. When you mutably reborrow a slice, it must produce a slice with a new lifetime:

```rust
let mut x = [1, 2, 3];
// We'll say this reference has lifetime 'a
let slice = &mut x[..];
// This one has a new lifetime that's distinct from 'a
let slice2 = &mut slice[1..];
```

This means you can't return `GlkArray<'a>` from `IndexMut::index_mut`. And the trait is written so that it is impossible to specify a working lifetime for `GlkArray`.

In addition, you can't return references to temporary values. Which means returning `&mut GlkArray` will not work, since you must create a new `GlkArray` inside the function. This also applies to `Index`.

There is one way around both of these, which is to modify the original `GlkArray` and return a reference to that. But this probably wouldn't be acceptable as a side effect of indexing.

Instead, you can write your own indexing function. You won't be able to use the indexing operator `[_]` but it will otherwise work.

```rust
impl GlkArray<'_> {
    // The return of this function cannot be Self
    pub fn get_mut<'a, I>(&'a mut self, index: I) -> Option<GlkArray<'a>>
    where
        I: SliceIndex<[u8], Output = [u8]> + SliceIndex<[u32], Output = [u32]>,
    {
        match self {
            Self::U8(slice) => slice.get_mut(index).map(GlkArray::U8),
            Self::U32(slice) => slice.get_mut(index).map(GlkArray::U32),
        }
    }
}
```